# Energy conservation, photon, distance

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor, energy-conservation, distance

From Weinberg 1972 Gravitation and Cosmology Principles, when discussing the luminosity distance, he talked about due to light wavelength being stretched as well as time interval stretched, in the "flux" expression we have the scale factor squared. At the end though, he said this could also be derived from energy conservation. I don't know what that means exactly (the references are books instead of concise answers to this). If anyone knows how to arrive the same conclusion using energy conservation $(T^{\mu \nu})_{;,\nu}=0$, please illuminate.

> where $A$ is the proper area of the mirror
> $$A\equiv\pi b^2$$
> However, each photon emitted with the energy $h\nu_1$ will be red-shifted to energy $h\nu_1 R(t_1)/R(t_0),$ and photons emitted at time intervals $\delta t_1$ will arrive at time intervals $\delta t_1 R(t_0)/R(t_1),$ where as always $t_1$ is the time the light leaves the source, and $t_0$ is the time the light arrives at the mirror. Thus the total power $P$ received by the mirror is the total power emitted by the source, its *absolute luminosity* $L,$ times a factor $R^2(t_1)/R^2(t_0),$ times the fraction (14.4.11):
> $$P=L\left(\frac{R^2(t_1)}{R^2(t_0)}\right)\left(\frac{A}{4\pi R^2(t_0)r_1^2}\right)$$
> The apparent luminosity $l$ is the power per unit mirror area, so
> $$l = \frac{P}{A} = \frac{LR^2(t_1)}{4\pi R^4(t_0)r_1^2}\tag{14.4.12}$$
> In a Euclidean space the apparent luminosity of a source at rest at distance $d$ would be $L/4\pi d^2,$ so in general we may define the *luminosity distance* $d_L$ of a light source as
> $$d_L \equiv \left(\frac{L}{r\pi l}\right)^{1/2}\tag{14.4.13}$$
> and (14.4.12) may therefore be written
> $$d_L = R^2(t_0)\frac{r_1}{R(t_1)}\tag{14.4.14}$$
> (This calculation could aslso have been carried out without using quantum theory by applying the energy-conservation equation $(T^{\mu\nu})_{;\nu}=0$ to the radiation emitted by the source.$^{15}$)

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Let's say the wavelength doubles (which reduces the energy of the light by a factor of two), that means that the time for the same amount of light to arrive on Earth also doubles (which reduces the power by an additional factor of two). That means that in total the power (luminous flux) is down by a factor of four.